# python uncertainties and correlation

Tags: python, uncertainty

With the "uncertainties" package python is quite powerful in propagating uncertainties through calculations. Is there a possibility to also include correlations? Let's say, I fit some data with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` which returns the optimal fit parameters and their correlation matrix, often called `popt` and `pcov`. Now I want to evaluate a function `f(popt)`.

Without correlations one can e.g. do it as follows (in 2D)

```
f(p0, p1):
    return p0 * unumpy.exp(p1)

p0 = ufloat(popt[0], pcov[0,0]**0.5)
p1 = ufloat(popt[1], pcov[1,1]**0.5)
result = f(p0, p1)
```

with whataver function `f`. This neglects the correlation of p0 and p1. In the documentation of "uncertainties" correlations are mentioned, but I don't really understand if and how I can apply it on my problem.

Edit: well this seems to work, but honestly, I do not really understand what it does and if this is really the correct solution.

```
import numpy as np
import uncertainties
from uncertainties import ufloat, unumpy

def f(p0, p1):
    return p0 * unumpy.exp(p1)

popt = np.array([1, 2])
pcov = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

p0, p1 = uncertainties.correlated_values(popt, pcov)
print(f(p0, p1))  # 7+/-25

p0 = ufloat(popt[0], pcov[0,0]**0.5)
p1 = ufloat(popt[1], pcov[1,1]**0.5)
print(f(p0, p1))  # 7+/-17
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had to work through basically the same problem, and I also found the [relevant part of the manual](https://uncertainties-python-package.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html?highlight=covariance#covariance-matrix) confusing.  As of this posting, their "example" of defining a correlated system using `uncertainties.correlated_values` is literally retyping a covariance matrix that they obtained half a page earlier by applying `uncertainties.covariance_matrix` to a pair of uncorrelated variables and a function.  This is neither a minimal example nor a natural application of `uncertainties.correlated_values`.

The short answer is that when you declare multiple `ufloat` objects, `uncertainties` always defines correlations among these objects.  But to *assign* those correlations when declaring a sequence of variables, you have to make the declaration using the `uncertainties.correlated_values` method and not using the `uncertainties.ufloat` method.

The following illustrates how various covariance methods interact with fit parameters and error propagation.

First, we need some correlated fit parameters.

```
import uncertainties
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

#define fitting model
def model(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b

#generate ydata that will produce significant parameter correlations
xdata=np.asarray([0,1,2,3,4,5])
ydata=np.zeros(len(xdata))
modata=np.zeros(len(xdata))

for i in range(len(xdata)):
    ydata[i]=xdata[i]**2 + xdata[i]**0.5

#fitting the data to the model specifies how correlated a and b are. 
par,cov=curve_fit(model,xdata,ydata)
print(par,cov)

#define the function we wish to propagate the parameters a and b through
def func(a,b):
    return a**3 + 2*b
```

Next, let's do error propagation without `uncertainties` so that we know what values it should generate. Note that manually typing out derivatives like this is often impractical, so the following method is not a good general approach.

```
fval = func(par[0],par[1]) #should evaluate to 152.76871905750235
dfa = (3*(par[0])**2) #should evaluate to 87.9417774777352
dfb = 2

#ferr should evaluate to 55.90407506588157
ferr = ( dfa**2 *cov[0][0] + dfb**2 *cov[1][1] + 2*dfa*dfb*cov[0][1] )**0.5
print('estimated value {:.1f}'.format(fval))
print('correlated uncertainty {:.1f}'.format(ferr))

#ferr_uncorr should evaluate to 59.36418474861461
ferr_uncorr = ( dfa**2 *cov[0][0] + dfb**2 *cov[1][1] )**0.5
print('uncorrelated uncertainty {:.1f}'.format(ferr_uncorr))
print('\n')
```

We would like to obtain the same results using `uncertainties`.  This requires us to declare a *system* of correlated variables, and `uncertainties.correlated_values` is the method used accomplish this. As luck would have it, `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` has already generated both a sequence of mean values and a covariance matrix.  We just need to assign them to objects that `uncertainties` can actually work with, objects that we will call `pA` and `pB`.  If you had to explicitly type out the inputs, you would have an expression like `uncertainties.correlated_values([a_val, b_val],[[cov_aa, cov_ab], [cov_ba, cov_bb]])`.

```
pA,pB = uncertainties.correlated_values(par, cov)
```

As an aside, we can print both the system we just defined and the original parameter covariance matrix to verify that they represent the same array of numerical values.

```
print (cov)
print (uncertainties.covariance_matrix([pA,pB]))
```

Having correctly declared the correlations, `uncertainties` will handle correlated error propagation correctly.

```
corr_F = func(pA,pB)
print('correlated {:.3u}'.format(corr_F))
```

If we just declare the parameters as individual ufloats, we are still generating a covariance matrix, but the relevant off-diagonal elements have been automatically assigned to zero in the background.  So when we propagate on `pA2` and `pB2`, we get the uncorrelated result.

```
pA2 = uncertainties.ufloat(par[0],cov[0][0]**0.5)
pB2 = uncertainties.ufloat(par[1],cov[1][1]**0.5)
print(uncertainties.covariance_matrix([pA2,pB2]))

uncorr_F = func(pA2,pB2)
print('uncorrelated {:.3u}'.format(uncorr_F))
```

Finally, let's address the kind of covariance matrix that was given in place of a minimal example in the manual.  `a` and `b` are random variables, and therefore `f(a,b)` is also a random variable.  So in both the correlated and uncorrelated cases, we can generate a covariance matrix relating `a`, `b` **and** `f(a,b)`.  The extra matrix elements tell you the variance of `f(a,b)` and the individual `a-f(a,b)` and `b-f(a,b)` correlations.

```
print(uncertainties.covariance_matrix([pA,pB,func(pA,pB)]))
print(uncertainties.covariance_matrix([pA2,pB2,func(pA2,pB2)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [User Guide](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/user_guide.html#index-9) example:

```
(u2, v2, sum2) = uncertainties.correlated_values([1, 10, 21], cov_matrix)
```

In your case I guess you may just write:

```
p0, p1 = uncertainties.correlated_values(popt, pcov)
```

Comment: I have edited the question, your solution seems to do something, but I don't really understand what. Can you explain it?